# Accelerometer Orientation (LIS3DH)

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, accelerometer

Newbie here!
I’m trying to make a pocket level using an LIS3DH but I don’t know how to “reset” all the axis to start reading from a certain orientation since my LIS3dh won’t be mounted flat and will change often.
Ideally whenever the level starts it would start reading everything at 0 no matter the orientation.
I’m sure it’s just math, but it’s way over my head to begin to understand it.

Starting with the absolute basics I’m using the adafruit lib. I can easily get all the readings, and I understand they are acceleration forces. But how do I start them all from 0?

Initially I was thinking to take the very first reading and store it, then add or subtract the new readings from the originals based on if the new numbers are higher or lower than original (subjectively) but that only works in some instances which means that it wasn’t a good solution.

I don’t have specific code to share as I’m using the adafruit LIS3DH example.

Here’s a reading from the sensor of it not flat

`X: -11408 Y: -3152 Z: 10560 X: -6.87 Y: -1.87 Z: 6.27 m/s^2`

And here’s readings closer to a flat surface

`X: -80 Y: 704 Z: 16176 X: -0.02 Y: 0.46 Z: 9.86 m/s^2`

Comment: Take an initial reading. Convert that to a 3D vector. Normalize it. That's "zero". Take any other reading. Convert it to a 3D vector. Normalize it. The angle between those two vectors is the angle of the level. This is maths, not Arduino.

Comment: "subtract the new readings from the originals [...] only works in some instances" - that's exactly what you have to do. When doesn't it work?

Comment: The last 3 number from the Adafruit example look to be the gyroscope.  Unless you are doing something like motion tracking (i.e. 3D gaming) or a "very reactive" tilt compass you don't need to bother w/those.

Answer (score 2):

Consider taking on this project in sever steps.  Some you might do now and other later if necessary

First, accelerometers do not usually need alignment.  But if accuracy and reproducibility is important, a project may benefit from finding any offset a single accelerometer may need and finding any magnitude adjustments between the three accelerometers.  Using gravity rotate each accelerometer through their maximum negative and positive values.  Use these values to find an offset such that the absolute values are equal for each individual accelerometer.  Then select one accelerometer as the bases and find the appropriate coefficients to normalize the other two accelerometers such that the absolute values of all maximums and minimum are equal.  As hinted, this is one of the step you can skip until later if necessary.  If you need a more thorough explanation you can find it in section 2 of [this STMicro document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjm6-qnsevwAhUFCs0KHY8uCk8QFjAAegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fapplication_note%2Fdm00119044-parameters-and-calibration-of-a-lowg-3axis-accelerometer-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw22kLvmCx7xWx_J4t54VvCK).

To find angles it would be best to consider the classic airplane example where pitch (nose up or down) and roll (rotation around the axis passing through the nose and tail).  [Here](https://theccontinuum.com/2012/09/24/arduino-imu-pitch-roll-from-accelerometer/) is a good submersible Arduino project to consider. In this project the accelerometer Z axis is pointed down and the X to the side.  To find ROLL the author calculates the inverse tangent of the negative of the ratio of acceleration in the X direction over the acceleration in the Z direction.

[image]

The pitch calculation is a bit more involved.  This can be found by taking the inverse tangent of the acceleration in the Y direction over the square root of the sum of the square of the X plus Y acceleration.

[image]

That out of the way, now consider how to zero the angles out.  First decide on if you will adjust the roll or the pitch.  Let's consider the roll case.  Record the current roll angle and subtract it from the current calculated roll angle before displaying it as zero.  Now rotate your accelerometer such that you do it around the Y axis (remember, we are only considering the roll case and do not want to change the Y accelerometer's reading!).  If you have done the math correctly, the displayed angle will be the difference between when you started and finished your rotation.

All that out of the way, now consider what would happen if you rotated your accelerometer through a roll position where the acceleration in the Z direction falls to zero.  Your trigonometric inverse tangent function for roll would go to infinity!  In the physical world, where gimbals are used for air and space navigation, this is referred to as [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)!

What to do about Gimbal lock?!  Well, it's a story that starts in 1843 (yeah, that does sound odd doesn't it WRT air and space navigation).  In short, if you stop using classical trigonometry to convert acceleration to angle an start using [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) you avoid Gimbal lock entirely.  Quaternions use complex numbers to describe rotation in 3D space.  People who write 3D gaming programs absolutely love how Quaternions simplify their efforts.  This is another of those steps you don't have to do.  But doing so will make your project all the more robust.

(BTW, [this is the STMicro LIS3DH data sheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lis3dh.pdf).)

Comment: You're new @CarmexLover13.  If the above answers your question select it as the correct answer.  If you want to wait and try it fist to see if it works that's ok too.  Or write a comment/question here if something is not clear and I'll edit the answer.  Feel free to edit your question too if you find you forgot to ask something in particular.

Comment: I'm not intentionally ignoring. I'm attempting to understand enough trig to be able to test this.. it's currently way over my head ha.

Comment: I fixed the link to the 1st STMicro document.  Maybe that will help.  Review the unit circle.  Get a feel for how angle and Sin and Cos relate.  Tan is just Sin/Cos.  After you wrap you head around that you can take a stab at converting the accelerameter's readings to angles.

Comment: If you want, you can skip over [trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) and jump to [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). Also, you are using an STMicro IMU chip.  If you are also using an STMicro processor you can simply skip over all of this by using STMicro development tools and ready made compass libraries.  It would be even better if you are using recent vintage STMicro development boards. But fair warning, unlike Arduino tools, these are complex tools meant for enterprise development.

Comment: I should have noted the pitch and roll are figured out. Resetting the starting leveling or accounting for gimbal lock I believe are the only hold up now and they share the same solution. 
Also for the time being I'm using an arduino uno, not stmicro based I don't believe
I'll be back when I understand quaternions a bit more